# Set args in -(id)init

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

is possible pass an args on an init method? I'm working with UITableViewController classes and UINavigatorController, when I push a new view whit:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[Class alloc] init] animated:YES];
```

I would also pass a string to that controller, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just define your own initializer for your view controller subclass:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style andSomeParameter:(NSString *)param
{
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style]) {
        myInstanceVariable = [param retain];
    }
    return self;
}
```

(This is for a subclass of `UITableViewController`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! And for a subclass of UIViewController?

Comment: Pretty much the same, except you wouldn't call `initWithStyle:` on `super` but probably `initWithNibName:bundle:`.

Answer (score 2):

It is not only possible, but it is normal and very common. In fact, it is quite common to have multiple initializers in classes where each initializer has a different combination of args, allowing you to initialize a class in different ways.

As you find yourself creating more than one initializer for a class, you should be sure to follow the best practices for making one initializer the "designated initializer". Here is [a link](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-initializers.html) to an article that demonstrates the principle of designated initializers.